# Cannot add Meteor package SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: macos, meteor

I just installed Meteor on OS X 10.10 and was able to create a new project, but I cannot add any packages.

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or
see this page for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

 => Errors while adding packages:

While downloading numtel:mysql@1.0.3...:
error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Your package catalog may be out of date.
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

First of all, I am behind a corporate firewall and I have the company's CA cert (which all the devices' certificates are signed with) installed in the System and login keychains. Everything else works fine: curl, npm, Chrome, etc. The only time I ever came close to something like this was using Python's pip command, but even that I was able to use the --cert option to point it to the CA cert to bypass the self signed certificate errors it was throwing.

After seeing several other postings from those with the same issue, people have been able to set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables with some success. However, this is not a viable option for me, as the company has dozens of these devices and you never connect to the same one twice it seems.

I tried it anyways after finally discovering the correct port to use on one of them, and alas, I am greeted with the following error:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or
see this page for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

 => Errors while adding packages:

While downloading numtel:mysql@1.0.3...:
error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Your package catalog may be out of date.
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

Notice how this time you see "error: tunneling socket could not be established" in addition to the "SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN" error.

Short of manually downloading and installing the packages from Atmosphere via Chrome (not a good idea) or trying this outside the firewall (not going to happen unfortunately), I'm not sure what I can do here to make this work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Not really. Best I could do was to checkout to Git repos of the packages into a "packages" folder at the root of the project, then "meteor add packagename" from there. Only issue is you have to download any dependencies those packages may have manually as well. With Meteor 1.3, it will be possible to use NPM for package management, so I'm hoping Atmosphere will die off after that. No need for anything other than NPM in the first place.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had lot of issue of self signed certificate with my corporate laptop, I found the magic "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0" env variable which allow me to fix any issue.

Warn it is totaly unsafe because there is no more certifcate verification, unfortunetly this is the only thing I could do.

On windows I use the command `$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` before launching any command with npm.